# Trying to remove duplicate observations by a particular variable in R

Tags: r, duplicates

Have a large data frame of test results for patients , which also has their ID as a variable. There are many patients who have tested several times so have multiple test results (negative or positive) in the dataset, listed under the variable 'result'. I've gotten the duplicate count with

`which(duplicated(dataset$ID))`

...where dataset is my dataset, and ID is the patient ID variable. Simple enough.
What I want to see now is, from the duplicate records, how many have a positive result. If a patient tests negative all times, its counted as a negative. If a patient tests positive even once (out of however many times tested), it counts as a positive. So I need to see how many unique positive results there are in my dataset. I'm completely stumped. Its a brain tickler for sure...

Comment: Can you show a small example and expected output

Comment: Will help in any way I can. Your suggested code is returning a value of 382, where it should be something in the 2000-3000 range, for positive cases. I can send you a blinded copy of the dataset, with relevant variables intact. Would you prefer that?

Comment: Would you be interested in looking at the data?

Comment: https://github.com/areza7/test-dataset

Comment: I get 1779 based on the data provided

Comment: Also, the total number of 'POS' is `with(dataset, sum( result == 'POS', na.rm = TRUE))#
[1] 5965`

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are total 28206 people in the dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

n_distinct(dataset$ID)
#[1] 28206
```

To count how many of them were tested positive atleast once we can do :

```
dataset %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(result = any(result == 'POS', na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  count(result)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  result     n
#  <lgl>  <int>
#1 FALSE  23352
#2 TRUE    4854
```

So from this, we can say that 4854 people were tested positive whereas 23352 were never tested positive. `23352 + 4854` gives 28206.

---

In base R, we can do this using `aggregate` and `table` which gives the same result.

```
table(aggregate(result~ID, dataset, function(x) 
       any(x == 'POS', na.rm = TRUE), na.action = NULL)$result)


#FALSE  TRUE 
#23352  4854
```

Comment: Ronak - thanks so much for this. Would you also be able to generate a 2nd subset of the ID nos. that are positive as well?

Comment: @areza You can do `dataset %>% group_by(ID) %>%summarise(result = any(result == 'POS', na.rm = TRUE)) %>% filter(result)` to get all the `ID`'s.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr` without any grouping

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  filter(result == 'POS') %>%
  distinct(ID) %>% 
  nrow
#[1] 4854
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nrow(unique(setDT(dataset)[result == 'POS'], by = 'ID'))
#[1] 4854
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
nrow(unique(subset(dataset, result == 'POS', select = ID)))
#[1] 4854
```

Comment: thank you akrun for your time spent on this. Ronak has got what I needed exactly, but I was able to learn from your code also. It helped in determining no of positives without the duplicate entries, as an aside.

Comment: @areza In the bginning you said, `Will help in any way I can. Your suggested code is returning a value of 382, where it should be something in the 2000-3000 range, for positive cases.` How is the outuput of 4854 in the 2000-3000 range?